# Exchange Receive Connectors keeps disappearing

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011, exchange

We're having troubles with sending/receiving mails with SBS2011. The 3 default Receive Connectors of SBS2011 are present(Default SBS2011, Windows SBS Internet Receive SBS2011 and Windows SBS Fax Sharepoint Receive SBS2011), but they are not configured properly.

I my knowledge, I know that the 3 permission groups that must be checked in 'Default SBS2011' are: Exchange users, Exchange servers and Legacy Exchange Servers. However, I need to check Anonymous users for our people to receive mail. If not checked, we get the following response

```
    Your message wasn't delivered due to a permission or security issue
    (#<IP #5.7.1 smtp; 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated> #SMTP#)
```

In a normal, working environment, this 'Anonymous users' should be checked in the 'Windows SBS Internet Receive SBS2011' connector, right? When I do this, i'll get the same response when sending an email.

**Note: At this moment, I can receive/send mail without problems (but the configuration is not how it should be).**

To fix this, I tried 'Fix My Network', and indeed it gives me the following error:

```
"Exchange is not configured to communicate over your local network"
```

When I tell Windows to fix this, he fixes it without a problem, however, when I run Fix My Network again, it gives me the same problem! It's a weird loop.

After that, I tried the 'Connect to the internet' wizard. It completes, but at the end it gives me an error that my mail isn't configured properly and that I need to run the wizard again. I can do this, but it will always give the same error, so no luck.

**NOW THE WEIRD PART
My Default Connector will disappear a few times in a day and I need to recreate it. Of course, we don't receive any mail before it's recreated.**